# multiprocessing with Pool in python, and returned variables

Tags: python, pool, multiprocessor

I'm using some python scripts to process images.  An image is some between 500x500 or 4000x4000 pixels.  The scripts do iterations over every pixel, so they're time consuming, so I set up the multiprocessor function.  There's something I can't find any documentation on.. so, if I have the script iterate through with Pool.map one pixel at a time height-wise, it appends a dimension to the returned array.  I would usually have a returned array height, width, # of color channels, but the mp functions would return a list instead of an array that is height, height, width, # of color channels, 1 extra channel for every iteration. OK.. so the child processes put their data into their own slice of memory space, which is fine.. but what exactly are the details?  I can't find it, should I just take the last number on the stack?  take an array that is now  height, 0:height, 0:width, 0:channel count, and reshape it to the array size I would have gotten as usual?  Or is it the 1st one?  I can't find this information

Comment: You need to add relevant pieces of code (probably simplified), otherwise this hard to answer.

Comment: Yes... I understand.  I actually solved my problem.. but it took me 2 days.  Maybe my real question.. people are writing books about Python left and right, and they're mostly terrible